# Angular filter confusing 1000, 100, 10

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with a database in which a field is either 10, 100, or 1000. Filtering to show only the "10" records also shows the "100" and "1000" records. Is there a simple way to fix this or should I write a custom filter?

Comment: It would since it returns all the records `containing` the search filter. You would have to write your own filter with `==` operator

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the standard | filter you'll have to include the final parameter of true to force exact comparison.

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in myArray | filter:{ value: 100 }: true">
    ...
</div>
```

Check it out in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter